# receiving dropzone files in Django views

Tags: django, dropzone

Could anyone help me to receive dropzone input in a function view in Django?
I wrote this code in my template for dropzone:

`index.html`:

```
 <form  method="post" action="{% url 'index' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone" >
                                    {% csrf_token %}                          

                            </form>
```

and for `URLs.py`:

```
 url('^$', views.UI_index, name='index'),
```

and in `views.py` I receive the posted file by  `UI_index` function:

```
def UI_index(request):
file_upload_message=''
if request.method=='post':
    f = request.FILES['file']
    file_upload_message='the file is received!'

 return render(
    request,
    'cta_UI/index.html',
    {'file_upload_message':file_upload_message},
    )
```

in the `index.html` I receive the value of `file_upload_message` like `{{file_upload_message}}` but it doesn't seem to work properly, it seems that the condition of `if request.method=='post'` doesn't work, then how I can post the uploded file to a view? when the post metheod is exactly executed in dropzone?
Although it is not my real project it is the first step to receive a file in view...please help me by that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[request.method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method)

you can try following code

```
def UI_index(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        up_file = request.FILES['file']
        if up_file:
            destination = open('/tmp/' + up_file.name, 'wb+')
            for chunk in up_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
            destination.close()
            file_upload_message='the file is received!'
        else:
            file_upload_message='the file is missing!'



    return render(request,'cta_UI/index.html',
        {'file_upload_message':file_upload_message},)
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work:( , may be because I receive files from a template with post method and I try to show the result in the same template...But I need such a process in my code(receiving file from dropzone in one page and showing the result in the same page)

Comment: I have removed "return httpresponse". you can send both response on same page.